# Dialog Removes All My Binds That are not related to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

Everytime I use dialog, all my other elements bind get lost, for example, I bind click event of elements with class '.submit-button' it works fine until I open a dialog...

Any idea?

Yours,
Diogo

edit:
Example:
Sure!

```
<span onclick="normalDialog()">Open Dialog</span>
<span class="submit-butto">alert ok</span>

<script>
$('.submit-butto').click(function(){
    alert('Ok');
});

function normalDialog(){
    $("#dialog").dialog({
    title: 'Hello',
    bgiframe: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    height:160,
    width:290,
    modal: true,
    overlay: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        opacity: 0.5
    },
    buttons: {
        "Close": function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

When I click 'open dialog','alert ok' stops working...

Comment: Could you please give us some code example ?

Comment: Edit your question with a larger sample code please

Comment: Strange, Ive made a test here http://jsfiddle.net/w2XKM/
and it works fine =\...

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it was nothing related to dialog,
Found this line on my code, it was resetting everything:

```
jQuery.cache = { };
```